# Swift inline conditional?

Tags: swift, conditional-statements

How do I do this in Swift ?

```
(someboolexpression ? "Return value 1" : "Return value 2")
```

(no I have not read the whole manual yet... I probably missed it on page 2!)

OK so its on page 91 and the above appears to be correct.  However I am trying to use this in a string like so:

```
println(" some string \(some expression ? "Return value 1" : "Return value 2")"
```

but the compiler is not happy.  Any idea if this if possible?

This is as close as I have been able to get

```
let exists = "exists"
let doesnotexist= "does not exist"

println("  something \(fileExists ? exists : doesnotexist)")
```

Comment: It's probably an oversight in the grammar, and you might want to file a bug on it.  I haven't checked the grammar for this, but it could be worth noting that it doesn't like escaped literals, only variables.  Ie. you cannot do this: println("hello \\("world")"), but you can do this: let world = "world"; println("hello \\(world)"), as you noted.  Summed up, it seems to want a variable and not an expression.

Comment: I'll do that, cheers.  In the meantime I'll accept @MikeS answer as the best option for now

Comment: you need a space after `let doesnotexist` or an preprocessor error will occur and make sure you have declared `let fileExists: Bool` some where before the `println` statement which should actually be `print` as of Swift 2.0. Otherwise I tried your code it works just fine

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you're looking for a one-liner to do that, you can pull the `?:` operation out of the string interpolation and concatenate with `+` instead:

```
let fileExists = false // for example
println("something " + (fileExists ? "exists" : "does not exist"))
```

Outputs:

> something does not exist

Comment: why is this not compiling to me? `        let answer =  (enterName_text == nil)? "" : enterName_text.text!
`

Comment: @EladBenda this would be better not as a comment, but as a separate question with details on what enterName_text is and the error you're getting. Best guess though is that you really want: if let answer = enterName_text?.text { ... }

Comment: When I first tried this ternary operator, I thought it did not work in Swift. Looked here and found this answer. The problem (coming from a C/C++ background) was not putting a space between the '?' and the first argument. The '?' is treated specially in Swift for optional values and the space character makes it clear that it is really a ternary operator.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the new *Nil-Coalescing Operator*, introduced in **Swift 3**. It will return default value if `someOptional` is `nil`.

```
let someValue = someOptional ?? ""
```

Here, if `someOptional` is `nil`, this operator will assign `""` to `someValue`.

Comment: This is such a swifty answer! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 20):

```
var firstBool = true
var secondBool: Bool

firstBool == true ? (secondBool = true) : (secondBool = false)
```

If in this case, it changes the secondBool to whatever the firstBool is. You can do this with integers and strings too

Comment: Do not do this. The proper way is much simpler. The general form should be: `secondBool = firstBool ? true : false`. But in this example, you only need `secondBool = firstBool`.

Answer (score 11):

It is called a "**ternary operator**".

With regards to @Esqarrouth's answer, I think a better format would be:

**Swift 3:**

```
var firstBool = true
var secondBool: Bool

secondBool = firstBool ? true : false
```

This is the same as:

```
var firstBool = true
var secondBool: Bool

if (firstBool == true) {
    secondBool = true
} else {
    secondBool = false
}
```

Answer (score 9):

simple solution i used in my projects

**Swift 3+**

```
var retunString = (state == "OFF") ? "securityOn" : "securityOff"
```

Answer (score 7):

You were oh so close. Just needed to assign it to a variable:

```
self.automaticOption = (automaticOptionOfCar ? "Automatic" : "Manual")
```

#### Edit:

> Any idea why that same expression can't be embedded in a string?

You can do that:

```
let a = true
let b = 1
let c = 2

println("\(a ? 1: 2)")
```

Comment: Any idea why that same expression can't be embedded in a string?

Comment: Mmm but this does not work `println("something \(automaticOptionOfCar ? "Automatic" : "Manual")")` ?

Answer (score 6):

Well,

If you concatenate the conditional with the string using the + operator, it should work.

Therefore, Mike is correct.

```
var str = "Something = " + (1 == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")
```

Answer (score 5):

I have use inline conditional like this :

isFavorite function returns a Boolen

`favoriteButton.tintColor = CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.isFavorite(placeId: place.id, type: 0) ? UIColor.white : UIColor.clear`

`tourOperatorsButton.isHidden = place.operators.count != 0 ? true : false`

Answer (score 1):

For Multiple Condition this can work like this

```
 let dataSavingTime: DataSavingTime = value == "0" ? .ThirtySecs : value == "1" ? .Timing1 : .Timing2
```

Answer (score -1):

One line condition without if and ternary operator

```
let value = "any"
// set newValue as true when value is "any"
let newValue = value == "any"
print(newValue)
//answer: true
```